# AWS Amplify AppSync Subscription: data returning null

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I was working on my Amplify App and I had subscriptions working fine with this:

### graphql:

```
type Item @model(subscriptions: null)
    @auth(rules: [
        {allow: owner},
        {allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"], operations: [create, update, read, delete] }
  ]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  files: String
}


type Subscription {
    itemUpdated(id: ID): Item @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateItem"])
}
```

---

### js:

```
const handleSubscription = (data) => {
  if (data.value.data.itemUpdated) {
    setItemObj(data.value.data.itemUpdated);
  }
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(subscriptions.itemUpdated, {
        id,
      }),
    ).subscribe({
      next: handleSubscription,
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

---

In the handleSubscription method, when the app made a mutation call to the Item, the return data  (`data.value.data.itemUpdated`) would have the correct data.

Now, for reasons I am obviously unclear about, I can still see the subscription event fire when a mutation occurs, but the return data (`data.value.data.itemUpdated`) is consistently null.

I have tried to remove the `{allow: owner}` rule from the graphql schema's auth field as [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770359/aws-amplify-appsync-subscription-not-working-correctly) suggests - which did not work (aside: I am still curious as to why that would work in the first place, but I do not have enough rep to comment).

While writing this, my thoughts were that I am going to try to create a new Item without the `{allow: owner}` rule and try again, if that works I will report back, but my question will pivot to asking why and asking then how can I ensure Items are private to the owner still? Lastly, I am almost positive I had the `{allow: owner}` rule in there when it was working too, but I could be mistaken.

I have also tried:

- tested with updating different Item fields
- let amplify cli rebuild my graphql js files
- changed code around, i.e

  - removed the `return () => subscription.unsubscribe();`
  - made the input more specific `API.graphql(graphqlOperation(subscriptions.itemUpdated, {input: { id: id },})` (which I am sure does not matter, but I wanted to try.)

I am just not sure what is going on here. This all seems so simple and it must be something dumb I am missing...I know I will figure it out eventually, but I wanted to tap anyone here in case.

### Versions:

- `"aws-amplify": "^3.0.24"`
- `"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^0.2.15"`
- `"react": "^16.13.1"`
- `amplify-cli: 4.29.0`

Please let me know if I left any important information out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.. just a dumb thing like I thought. My bad for wasting anyone's time!

```
API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(subscriptions.itemUpdated, {
         id: Id,
      }),
    ).subscribe({
      next: handleSubscription,
    });
```

it was the `id: Id,` parameter. I had the `Id` var before named as `id` and js allows for shorting `{name: name}` to `{ name }` - I must have changed the `id` var and went right to `{input: { id: Id },}` which is the incorrect syntax for subscriptions.

Real bonehead move and I am appropriately embarrassed. Good lesson in bad naming even during testing.

Comment: I wish mine was this easy.  I just tried to tweak auth so my lambda could access GraphQL and now Angular is returning nulls.  I didn't touch the schema .. this feels like mutually assured destruction on a large project.

Comment: @Mark I'm having the same problem at the moment. I wanted another lambda to take advantage of my gql endpoint but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: @RoboKozo if I remember correctly when I tried to add new auth it changed the order and went from cognitio default to the new one.  I had to find where that was set in some of the amplify configuration to undo the order.  I’ll see if I can find the file when I get back to my computer.

Comment: @Mark in my case it was related to the fact that my mutation was only requesting a subset of the fields required by my mutation. So if your mutation returns `{ x, y, z }` but your subscription requests `{ x, y, foo }` you'll get a `null` for `foo`

Comment: @RoboKozo, yes I had that issue too because I had a Lambda executing commands against files uploaded and needed to add all fields to the query in order to properly get the websocket update back on my Angular Frontend.  Definitely fell victim to that.